# Variable arguments in C

Tags: c, function

Is there a way to read/access variable arguments like we read command line arguments from `argv[]`?

I'm aware of the `va_arg` way of doing it but just wondering if something like "argv" exists for this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "something like 'argv'"? Do you mean something like having a function `void foo(int argc, T* argv)`, where you can get `argc` items of type `T` from `argv`? If so, you can just pass an array with those semantics.

Comment: @Brian61354270 I meant, like how command line arguments to a program are stored in argv. (int main(int argc, char **argv)). Is there a similar way for reading variable arguments to a function ?

Comment: The only facility the C standard provides for accessing variable arguments is the `va_arg` method.

Comment: @akc5 you can pass an array + length, which is exactly what your C runtime is doing to call main. You won't get a "variable number of arguments" call syntax exactly, but you can always do `T args[] = {arg1, arg2, arg3}; foo(args, sizeof(args)/sizeof(T));`

Comment: You can pass a *sentinel*-terminated array: https://ideone.com/YWrkfI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only facility the C standard provides for accessing variable arguments is the `va_arg` method.

In general, it would be impossible (barring some gross extension to the language) for there to be any sort of `va_arg[i]` method of accessing variable arguments since `va_arg[i]` must have one fixed type but variable arguments can have any complete object type.

A C implementation might implement the `<stdarg.h>` features by organizing arguments into memory serially, and then it could be possible to access that memory yourself, including accessing it as an array of all the variable arguments have the same type. However, the means for doing so would not only not be portable to other C implementations but generally would not be supported by the specific C implementation.

Answer (score 1):

#### Actually, yes there's a way

###### ...with macro tricks.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// foo is a macro that'll take multiple strings and pass them to _foo
#define foo(...) _foo( sizeof((char *[]){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(char *), (char *[]){__VA_ARGS__})

void _foo(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("argc: %d\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    foo("Hello", "World");
}
```

#### How it works

It uses:

- `...` and `__VA_ARGS__`: the syntax for variadic arguments in macros
- `(char *[]){/*...*/}`: a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) to create a array of strings
- `sizeof(array) / sizeof(elem)`: a trick to get the number of elements in an array

The macro `foo` creates two arrays from the variadic parameters. The first array is used in the size trick, and passed to `argc`. The second is directly passed to `argv`.

Two of the above points have already been pointed out in the comments by @Brian61354270 and @Cubic, it was just a matter of putting the whole thing together. Especially @Cubic, who showed the same way but without a macro.

#### A few notes

- Unlike with `va_arg`, this technique can only be used when you have arguments of the same type.
- This uses a macro. Often, it implies that the macro arguments might be evaluated multiple times. Here *it looks like* the arguments are evaluated twice, but sizeof doesn't evaluate. So calling `foo(bar())` will only call `bar` once. (Which is pretty good, that's what we want)
- It doesn't behave exactly like the `main`'s `argc`/`argv`. For starters, I didn't put `NULL` at the end of argv. That's trivial to add though.

Comment: This is really interesting, combined with the accepted answer I have what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps referring to the way that functions like `printf` can take different arguments at different times?

`printf` is an example of a *variadic* function, and is declared as:

```
printf(char* format, ...);
```

Where the `...` means the following arguments can be of any type, and there can be any number of them.

These are processed by the caller using type `va_list` and macros `va_start`, `va_arg` and `va_end`, all defined in header file `<stdarg.h>`.

There are plenty of examples online that explain how this is used.

Comment: No. I was looking for something like `int main(int argc, char **argv)` but thanks a lot!